# Is there an application for managing drives mapping on windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Today, I have a set of batch files that allows me to switch between several drive mapping (and substitutions) configuration. I have a rather frequent need of these to switch between software configuration.

I would like to replace these set of batch files with some software that would have the following capability.

- Be able to map/unmap a drive letter to a network path.
- Be able to subst a drive letter to a local folder
- Be able to do both of the above both in the regular security context and in the elevated context (if the user is admin)
- Be able to work based on profile describing desired configuration. It shouldn't attempt to remap correctly mapped drives, just remap the ones that are incorrect or missing and unmap the extra ones.

Extra features that I could use but can also work without:

- Run a batch file once the profile has been applied.
- Apply a profile from the command line.
- Validate a profile from the command-line (make sure a given profile has been applied or return with an error code)

Anyone has a suggestion ?

Comment: Are you referring to `Group Policy Objects` that can map drives depending on the security filter?

Comment: No. I need to switch between profile on the fly in the same session besides, GPOs can't perform drive substitution.

Comment: Then I pose my next question: scripting via powershell?

Comment: I already have a bunch of batch files to do the job so powershell wouldn't help except make it less practical to run them. I know none of this if too fancy, but maintaining all these batch files (I have more than a dozen) is inconvenient and running the is prone to errors.